# Why does chrome try to load the unminified version of jQuery when including the minified version?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-source-map

The  `script` tag has a `src` attribute of `jquery-2.0.3.min.js`, but Chrome somehow requests for `jquery-2.0.3.js` as well. I am not able to understand as to why this happens.

Is there something wrong with `jquery-2.0.3` version?

Here is [the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTa4X.jpg) of Chrome developer tools debugging:

[image: Chrome Developer Tools screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

From the screenshot it seems you're including jQuery's source map file (`jquery-2.0.3.min.map`).

This file allows Chrome to more clearly debug the minified version of jQuery (`jquery-2.0.3.min.js`).

However, the source map file also tells Chrome to load the unminified version of jQuery (`jquery-2.0.3.js`), and since it does not exist locally you see the failed request.

**Solution**

Either do not include the source map file altogether, or add the unminified version of jQuery to the local directory as well.

[Read more about jQuery's source maps](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2013/01/the-magic-of-jquery-source-map.html).

Comment: A. If I don't use the source map file altogether, Chrome does not like it and throws error on missing jquery-2.0.3.min.map file.

B. In development and testing, I still can use unminified jQuery but when I move to production, (Chrome) users will find the same problem, won't they?

Comment: **A.** Have you tried clearing your cache? It could be that Chrome was still loading a cached version of `index.html` which still included the `script` tag of the map file. **B.** Yes, in production it's recommended not to use the unminified version, for obvious performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Boaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20261474/1009828) that seems your Chrome detect and use source maps.

To avoid loading source maps, from Chrome Dev Tools *Settings > General* deselect *"Enable JS source maps"* option.

See [Chrome DevTools>Debugging JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging?hl=it#source-maps)